# Type 'SalesforceDataQueryComponent.Utils.SfdcObjects+SfdcCollection is not supported for deserialization of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json-deserialization

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();    
// Deserialize the response to get an array of CUSTOM Cases
    var reportsList = jsSerializer.Deserialize<SfdcObjects.SfdcCollection<SfdcObjects.Assets>>(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(response));
```

throws an exception:

> Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Type 'SalesforceDataQueryComponent.Utils.SfdcObjects+SfdcCollection`1[
>   [SalesforceDataQueryComponent.Utils.SfdcObjects+Assets, SalesforceDataQueryComponent, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral]]' 
>   is not supported for deserialization of an array.

I can not figure it out the issue:

Objects:

```
namespace SalesforceDataQueryComponent.Utils
{
    class SfdcObjects
    {
        // Used for Authentication
        public class TokenResponse
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string issued_at { get; set; }
            public string refresh_token { get; set; }
            public string instance_url { get; set; }
            public string signature { get; set; }
            public string access_token { get; set; }
        }

        // All classes shown next are used to parse the HttpGet Response
        public class SfdcCollection<T>
        {
            public bool Done { get; set; }
            public int Size { get; set; }
            public string NextRecordsUrl { get; set; }
            public List<T> Records { get; set; }
        }

        public class SfdcAttributes
        {
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public string Url { get; set; }
        }

        public class Accounts : Account
        {
            public SfdcAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
        }

        public class Assets : Asset
        {
            public SfdcAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
        }

        public class CustomAssets : Assets
        {
            public string StringInstallDate { get; set; }
        }

        public class Users : User
        {
            public SfdcAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
        }

        public class CustomCase : Case
        {
            public string StringCreatedDate { get; set; }
        }

        public class CustomCases : CustomCase
        {
            public SfdcAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question to show the JSON you are trying to parse.

Comment: Also, can you update your question to tell us what serializer you are using?

Comment: I add the serializer that im using. And Im going to update with the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You do not include your response JSON in your question, however from the error message, your problem must be that the root JSON container in your response is an **array**.  A JSON array, according to the [JSON standard](http://json.org/), looks like this:

```
[value1, value2, ..., valueN]
```

JSON serializers map types that implement `ICollection` or `IEnumerable` from and to JSON arrays.

Your root object `SfdcCollection<T>`, however, is NOT a collection or enumerable, despite its name.  Instead it's a non-enumerable generic POCO:

```
    public class SfdcCollection<T> // No IEnumerable<T>
    {
        public bool Done { get; set; }
        public int Size { get; set; }
        public string NextRecordsUrl { get; set; }
        public List<T> Records { get; set; }
    }
```

Thus a serializer will map this to a JSON **object** (which is a set of key/value pairs and looks like `{"name1" : value1, "name2" : value2, ..., "nameN" : valueN }`) instead of an array.

You need to update your data model to the JSON you are actually receiving.  Try uploading your JSON to http://json2csharp.com/, it will automatically generate classes for you.

If you must use the classes in your question, you could [ask another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) about how to map the JSON you are actually receiving onto your required classes, using your desired serializer (e.g. Json.NET, `DataContractJsonSerializer`, `JavaScriptSerializer`, or etc.)